# Convert rows to column dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table, with condition that one product can have up to 4 labels (4 Label Names/LN, 4 Label Placements/LP):

```
PRODUCT_CODE    LABEL_NAME  PLACEMENT_DETAIL
---------------------------------------------
307960-010      Trademark   Bottom Left
307960-010      228119      Middle Left
307960-010      YCM Sticker Bottom Right
307960-015      Trademark   Bottom Left
307960-016      Trademark   Bottom Left
307960-017      Trademark   Bottom Left
307960-020      228119      Middle Left
307960-020      Trademark   Bottom Left
```

I want to show the table like following:

```
Product Code    LN1         LP1         LN2         LP2         LN3         LP3          LN4       LP4

307960-010      Trademark   Bottom Left 228119      Middle Left YCM Sticker Bottom Right        
307960-015      Trademark   Bottom Left                     
307960-016      Trademark   Bottom Left                     
307960-017      Trademark   Bottom Left                     
307960-020      228119      Middle Left Trademark   Bottom Left
```

I try using DECODE with defined Label Name or Placement but it's far from what I desired, since there are more than 20 kind of labels, here's how it looks:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT_CODE,  
    DECODE(LABEL_NAME,'Trademark',label_name) AS "LN1", 
    DECODE(PLACEMENT_DETAIL,'Bottom Left',PLACEMENT_DETAIL) AS "LP1",
    DECODE(LABEL_NAME,'228119',label_name) AS "LN2", 
    DECODE(PLACEMENT_DETAIL,'Middle Left',PLACEMENT_DETAIL) AS "LP2",
    DECODE(LABEL_NAME,'YCM Sticker',label_name) AS "LN3", 
    DECODE(PLACEMENT_DETAIL,'Bottom Right',PLACEMENT_DETAIL) AS "LP3"
-- etc until all labels declared
FROM
    (SELECT   
         PPL.*,
         PML.LABEL_NAME
     FROM   
         MES.PL_PRODCODE_LABEL PPL, MES.PL_MASTER_LABEL PML  
     WHERE       
         PPL.ID_LABEL = PML.ID_LABEL
         AND PPL.STATUS_USE = 'Y'
         AND PML.STATUS_USE = 'Y'
     ORDER BY 2
)
```

Here's the result:

```
PRODUCT_CODE    LN1         LP1          LN2    LP2          LN3            LP3

307960-010      Trademark   Bottom Left             
307960-010                               228119 Middle Left     
307960-010                                                   YCM Sticker    Bottom Right
307960-015      Trademark   Bottom Left             
307960-016      Trademark   Bottom Left             
307960-017      Trademark   Bottom Left             
307960-020                               228119 Middle Left     
307960-020      Trademark   Bottom Left
```

How to achieve such a result?

Thank you.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks, I'll keep in mind to avoid the old style join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [PIVOT](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot)

Before doing this, assign a `row_number()` starting at one for each product code (`partition by product_code`), sorted according to however you want to prioritize the labels.

In the `pivot` clause take the `min` (or `max`) of the labels and placements, for each of the possible number of entries for a product:

```
create table t (
  product_code varchar2(10),
  label_name   varchar2(20),
  placement    varchar2(20)
);

insert into t values ( '307960-010', 'Trademark', 'Bottom Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-010', '228119', 'Middle Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-010', 'YCM Sticker', 'Bottom Right' );
insert into t values ( '307960-015', 'Trademark', 'Bottom Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-016', 'Trademark', 'Bottom Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-017', 'Trademark', 'Bottom Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-020', '228119', 'Middle Left' );
insert into t values ( '307960-020', 'Trademark', 'Bottom Left' );

with rws as (
  select t.*, 
         row_number () over (
           partition by product_code
           order by label_name, placement
         ) rn
  from   t
)
  select * from rws
  pivot (
    min ( label_name ) ln, min ( placement ) lp
    for rn in ( 1, 2, 3 )
  );
  
PRODUCT_CODE    1_LN         1_LP           2_LN         2_LP           3_LN           3_LP           
307960-010      228119       Middle Left    Trademark    Bottom Left    YCM Sticker    Bottom Right    
307960-015      Trademark    Bottom Left    <null>       <null>         <null>         <null>          
307960-016      Trademark    Bottom Left    <null>       <null>         <null>         <null>          
307960-017      Trademark    Bottom Left    <null>       <null>         <null>         <null>          
307960-020      228119       Middle Left    Trademark    Bottom Left    <null>         <null>
```

Comment: Great, now it showing what I desired. Thank you sir  I need to learn more., have a great day.